# How to get specific column form mysql (PDO)?

Tags: php

I have this code and in "SELECT * FROM Blogi WHERE PostID=".

How to get each line separately so that takes postedBY, title, date, content by PostID

```
    <?php
     try{
        $Blog = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Blogi WHERE PostID=");
        $Blog->execute();
     }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }

     $fetch = $Blog->fetchAll();
   $usercount = $Blog->rowCount();
     if($usercount > 0){
         foreach($fetch as $f){
            $PostID = $f['PostID'];
            $PostedBY = $f['PostedBY'];
            $Title = $f['Title'];
            $Date = $f['Date'];
            $Content = $f['Content'];
         }
    }else{
      session_destroy();
      header('location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

I have very bad English, so I don't know anyone can understand this.

How to do it further this postID="" to that he would start to work?

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: `WHERE PostID="` that's unfinished.

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?  You have a malformed SQL query, so that's going to fail before you get any query output at all.  Once you fix that, what's wrong with the rest of your code?  Are you just asking how to write output to the page?

Comment: I want to make a blog. the post to take data from the database

Comment: How to fix this ="? What i need to add in =" to it work?

Comment: @Dexx: Any tutorial on PDO will show you how to use parameters in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done it in foreach loop... so add a line for output like... Also you aren't sending any PostID value to your query, be sure that you are sending a value for it.

```
foreach($fetch as $f){
    $PostID = $f['PostID'];
    $PostedBY = $f['PostedBY']
    $Title = $f['Title'];
    $Date = $f['Date'];
    $Content = $f['Content'];

    echo $PostID . " " . $Title . " " . $Date . " " . $Content . "<br />";
}
```